# Partial sums for a power series

Tags: power-series

I'm having trouble finding the formula for the partial sums of this series,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty\:}{nz^n}$$

where $z$ is a complex number. I'm not looking for the answer just a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: You can [use $\LaTeX$](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) to enter formulas, no need in oversized pictures.

Comment: See [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 2):

The terms in the sum are close to the derivative of a simple power of $z$. For the sum of those, you can use the formula for the geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

\begin{align*}
\frac{1 - z^{N+1}}{1-z}
&= 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots + z^N \\
\frac{d}{dz} \left( \frac{1 - z^{N+1}}{1-z} \right)
&= 1 + 2z + \cdots + Nz^{N-1} \\
z \frac{d}{dz} \left( \frac{1 - z^{N+1}}{1-z} \right)
&= \quad ? \\
\end{align*}